# Lyndon words over the binary alphabet that begin with "00"

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, riemann-zeta, oeis, lyndon-words

[Lydon words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) over the binary alphabet are strings of $1$s and $0$s such that all rotations of the word are *strictly* lexicographically later.
I've been looking at Lyndon words of length $n$, which are counted by OEIS sequence [A001037](https://oeis.org/A001037).

```
1 | 0,      1
2 | 01
3 | 001,    011
4 | 0001,   0011,   0111
5 | 00001,  00011,  00101,  00111,  01011,  01111
6 | 000001, 000011, 000101, 000111, 001011, 001101, 001111, 010111, 011111
```

In particular, though, I'm interested in the number of Lyndon words that begin with two or more $0$s.

I [generated all Lyndon words of length $n$](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-lyndon-words-of-length-n/) and counted those that start with two zeros. Starting at index $n = 1$ there are

```
0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 25, 48, 88, 168, 310
```

such words. For $n \geq 3$, this matches OEIS sequence [$A065491(n-1)$](https://oeis.org/A065491):

> Exponents in expansion of $\displaystyle\prod_{\textrm{prime }p\, \geq\, 3} \left(1 - \frac1{p^2-p-1}\right)$  as a product $\zeta(n)^{-a(n)}$.

That is, $$
\prod_{\textrm{prime }p\, \geq\, 3} \left(1 - \frac1{p^2-p-1}\right) = \zeta(0)^0 \cdot 
\zeta(1)^{-1} \cdot 
\zeta(2)^{-1} \cdot 
\zeta(3)^{-2} \cdot 
\zeta(4)^{-4} \cdot
\zeta(5)^{-7} \cdots
$$

I can't prove (or disprove!) this identity. Why are these two sequences equal? Or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Very curious. For the product $\prod_n \zeta(n)^{-a(n)}$, where does $n$ start? Also, I'll record this here for reference: http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/Moree-txfm.en.shtml on how to transform between $\prod_p (1-f/g)$ and $\prod_n \zeta(n)^{-a(n)}$

Comment: @bonsoon, thanks for the link! For the product, $n$ starts at 1. I've written out the first few terms to disambiguate.

Comment: The Lyndon words not starting with 00 are [A6206](https://oeis.org/A006206). All three sequences are Euler transforms of simple linear recurrences. Possibly this could help somehow.